# How to align a dynamic html div text inline with other text behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below dynamic text parallel to each other.

A Person who brings together people,new
ideas, and important resources  and
service models.A person who brings..

```
 **Download:Img**
```

A seeker of promising 
academic thinking,and
  **Download: Img**

but the download:Img div is not in-line other download:img.The paragraph maybe any number of lines but all the downlaod:img text should be in same line irrespective of the length of paragraph. 
I have tried line height CSS property but its changing the height for one Downlaod:img only but i need all the Downlaod:img text to be in same line.can anyone help?

Comment: Can you start a codepen.io link so we can get a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi I have uploaded an image to my post which i think is may help in knowing my question exactly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's impossible to debug layout just from text